# How to connect Excel Source via OLEDB or any other source in SSIS?

Tags: excel, ssis, integration, oledb, ssis-2017

Is there any other way rather than "Excel connection manager" to connect Excel as Source in SSIS.

I am asking this question because I have an issue with connecting Excel with "Excel Connection Manager" because in my system Excel 32 bit is installed and the Visual Studio version is 64 bit.

I tried connecting it with ODBC  but wasn't successful.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: No. I didn't find any useful answer to this.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions below? Why didn't replied to the answers so you will get more help

Comment: these are not related to my qestion.

Comment: I am asking for any ther ways to connect excel in ssis rather than Excel Connection Manager.

Like OleDB or Ado.net Connection?

Comment: Excel Connection Manager relies on OLEDB, the answers below are targeting what you mentioned `I have an issue with connecting Excel with "Excel Connection Manager" because in my system Excel 32 bit is installed and the Visual Studio version is 64 bit`. If running visual studio package in 32-bit didn't worked then installing AccessDatabaseEngine will surely works

Comment: Just try the suggestions and give a feedback, they must solve the main issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

[There is not Visual Studio 64-bit version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit), I think you should change the `Run64BitRuntime` Property to `False`:

- [FAQ - How to run SSIS Packages using 32-bit drivers on 64-bit machine](https://help.sentryone.com/dtsxchange/scr/faq%20-%20how%20to%20run%20ssis%20packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm)
- [SSIS run64bitruntime on 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614689/ssis-run64bitruntime-on-64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

**Install both AccessDatabaseEngine 32bit and 64bit**

If you need to install AccessDataBaseEngine x64 alongside with 32-bit installation, you need to run the installation in **passive mode**:

**Passive mode installation steps**

1. Open the Command Prompt by typing `cmd` in the Windows search box under the Start menu and selecting cmd.exe
2. Type the file path and file name of the 64-bit Access Database Engine 2010 install file, followed by a space and `/passive` (this runs the installation without showing any error messages).
3. Open the Registry Editor by typing `regedit` in the Windows search box under the Start menu and selecting `regedit.exe`
4. Delete or rename the `mso.dll` registry value in the following registry key:

   ```
   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\FilesPaths"
   ```

*More details and screenshots are found in the link below*

**Reference**

- [How to install 64-bit Microsoft Database Drivers alongside 32-bit Microsoft Office](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office.html)